Can the spinning dancer illusion be analyzed mathematically?
This is a type of Optical Illusion known as the Spinning Dancer Illusion:




It’s a famous optical illusion that many in this community are probably familiar with.
A single trajectory traced by an object on a screen can appear to rotate clockwise, and at the same time, it can also appear to rotate counterclockwise.
This illusion usually disappears when depth is
added to the object.
I believe that this kind of illusion can occur when the trajectories of an object projected onto a screen while rotating clockwise around a fixed axis coincide with those projected while rotating counterclockwise.
This might not be a mathematical problem but rather a psychological one.

However, I’m curious if this illusion can be analyzed mathematically, and I’d like to hear the thoughts of math experts on this.

Please remove the link, this will force readers to click into your link to understand your question.

You can try thinking about a 2D (Flatland-like) version of the scenario. In this graph, the black line is a projection of the red and blue lines on the line $y=-6$. Can you tell just by looking at the black line if it is the projection of the blue line or the red line?

Also note: when the dancer appears to be rotating anticlockwise (as seen from the top), her left leg appears to be raised, but when you perceive the rotation as clockwise, her right leg goes up!

@SohamSaha  Very good example. I also believe that matching the trajectory of the orthographic projection over time, whether it is clockwise or counterclockwise, can create the illusion of rotation in both directions depending on the viewer's perspective. While there may be countless graphs where the trajectories of the orthographic projections match in this way, it does not hold true for arbitrary graphs. I'm curious about the mathematical characteristics of a plane or solid figure that can create such an optical illusion

I believe that it will hold for any arbitrary shape. Rotating a figure $S$ clockwise, has the same parallel projection as rotating the mirror image of $S$ anticlockwise.

You should note that you are not rotating the same shape, once clockwise and then anticlockwise. You are rotating a shape once in clockwise orientation, and then reflecting it and rotating it anticlockwise.

@SohamSaha
I don't think it's possible for every shape. For example, consider an L-shaped figure with sides of length 3. When this shape is rotated 45 degrees clockwise and 45 degrees counterclockwise, the lengths of their projections appear to be different.

I think you missed my last comment.

@SohamSaha Do you mean that this always holds true for 'mirror images'?

See if this helps

The illusion is that you can’t tell from the parallel projection alone if you are looking at shape $S$ rotating clockwise, or looking at the reflected counterpart of $S$, rotating anticlockwise .

@SohamSaha
Can it be understood that when an arbitrary shape rotates clockwise, its parallel projection looks identical to the parallel projection of its mirror image rotating counterclockwise, so based on the parallel projection alone, one can perceive it as rotating either clockwise or counterclockwise depending on the perspective?

@NOHWHIREA yes, exactly.

The illusion is possible only in exact parallel projection. A central projection always exhibits its depth by slightest length contraction by distance. This is one of the best trained part of the video analyzer directly coupled to the balance and movement apparatus.
The possibility of the illusion depends on the symmetry group of the object.
For the outer shape of a perfect woman you are not able to tell if its original or a mirror picture. As the educated group specialists know, in 3D euclidean space a mirror map at a vertical mirror does not exchange left and right, but direction front and back, that are possible to distingiush.
If you suppress this dimension, objects with a mirror plane loose their orientation.
If you add the asymmetry by showing the heart e.g. it's more difficult to switch the sense of rotation in the reconstructed 3D image in the video brain.
Finally, there is the psychological component of distraction.
The switch of rotation direction is happening far more easily, if one concentrates on the legs only, ignoring the naked woman shape,
The gray shape in  darkness is deeply engraved in the brain, it triggers switching off the analytic, critical  parts of the brain machine, concentrating on the expectation of breastfeading.
